# Hardware problem?? Can't install

Tags: boot, system-installation, screen

I have a secondary desktop that I run Linux on.

I hadn't really used it since a recent move. Now I decided to plug it in, switch the hard-drive, and do a fresh install on an empty drive.

I boot from an USB drive, and after the "DMI pool data" phase,

This is what pops up on my screen:

[image]

After a few seconds the monitor goes dark with the standard "no input" warning, then goes to standby. The computer seems to be unresponsive.

The POST screens were all fine, so I have no idea what is going on. Is my PC wrecked? Any idea what's doing this???

EDIT: The website is suggesting a pre-existing solution to the issue "my computer boots to a black screen". This situation is markedly different, as is evident from the attached screenshot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: This looks to me like it just needs the nomodeset option in the linked answer.